# Their intention/intentions are vital information

Tags: word-choice, subject-verb-agreement

Which one should I use in the sentence below?

> Their **intention**/**intentions** are vital information for us to make a decision.

In this context, I want to express that what other road users intend to do is important.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use **intentions**. "Are" is conjugated for the plural case, requiring the associated noun *intention* to be plural as well.

But beyond noun-verb agreement, *intentions* is still the best choice. If the singular form were used, it would mean that all road users share a single, unvarying intention. This is unlikely to fit the intended meaning of the sentence. The plural form allows for different intentions between different road users, as well as for a particular road user having different intentions at different points in time.